# Flask-script with argument and cron jobs

Tags: flask, cron, flask-script

I have a flask application running with flask-script extension.
A function (with 3 arguments) is placed in my cron and ended by:

```
if name == "main": 
    manager.run()
```

Like mentioned in the flask-script doc - [link](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest)

This function works fine when I call it directly in the console (like mentioned in the flask-script doc)

```
python myfunction.py functionpython arg1 arg2 arg3
```

but not in my cron (a necessary comment "# arg2 comment" is added).

```
*/1 * * * * /var/www/TWEETPOKE/myfunction.py functionpython arg1 arg2 arg3 # arg2 comment
```

When I run this script on a raspberry pi, I get no error from either cron or python.
Any clue?

Comment: You need to give more details. Any specific error message ? How does your myfunction.py code look like ?

Comment: Is `myfunction.py` executable? Have you included a shebang at the top of it (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python`)? You may need to include `python` in your cron task.

Comment: i tried all the solutions :
 - add shebang
 - include python (with or without path)

and myfunction.py is executable
(cf.if __name__ == "__main__":)

i'm a bit confused...

Comment: By executable I think dirn suggested "Did you do a `chmod +x` on your file?" because `if __name__ == "__main__":` doesn't mean a script is executable. You might consider calling it with python in the crontab if you don't have execution right (nor want to add it).